# Register ObjectMapper in Spring 4.1.3 to serialize Joda DateTime

Tags: java, spring-mvc, datetime, jackson, jodatime

I'm trying to configure ObjectMapper in my Web application to serialize/deserialise dates presented as Joda's DateTime in ISO 8601 format. I found useful library `jackson-datatype-joda` and it's module `JodaModule` so I've added dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

My Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="objectMapper"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
    p:indentOutput="true">

    <property name="featuresToDisable">
        <array>
            <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS" />
        </array>
    </property>

    <property name="modulesToInstall" value="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule" /> 
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

When I try to serialize this bean

```
public class Bean {
    private DateTime start = new DateTime();

    public DateTime getStart() { return start; }
    public void setStart(DateTime start) { this.start = start; }        
}
```

I get following output as long but instead want it to be in ISO 8601 format:

`{"start":1418337158933}`

I found that `JodaModule` also preloads if it is found in classpath so it is not neccessary to register it manually (see [github repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2fccf3ff4409a641c20947e8fca90308f7236c64/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java#L568)) but this code is invoked many times during application start.

I think the reason is that `ObjectMapper` is instantiated in some other place.

**UPDATE:** The problem was that there was one more file with Spring configuration where ObjectMapper was declared. Both solutions given in answers will work. Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create you custom ObjectMapper class like in the code below it will override default objectMapper and you don't need your xml configuration at all:

```
@Service
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        this.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        this.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    }
}
```

I've added this simple service to the simple spring boot application and got time in the expected format.

Comment: But for some strange reason it is not working for me. Researching deeper.

Comment: can you post all your project dependencies (with versions) and Rest controller?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Java configuration, it can be like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JodaDateTimeConfig {

@Bean
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    return objectMapper;
}
```